# apple-app-site-association universal link signing issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, openssl, ios-universal-app

I am working on universal linking , I have four files as mentioned below (through which my domain is SSL certifed),

```
ACertificate-1.cer
ACertificate-2.cer
ServerCertificate.cer
Private.key
```

and The Json file

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "ZY9H86N885.com.abc.Developementabc",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

with the below command i have signed the `apple-app-site-association` file

```
cat json | openssl smime -sign -inkey Private.key -signer ServerCertificate.cer -certfile ACertificate-1.cer -noattr -nodetach -outform DER > apple-app-site-association
```

i have no idea, where to put the second certificate `ACertificate-2.cer`, so i left it like that.

and i did all the points alerted in https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/

up to this point

> Your file should validate and return its contents with `openssl smime -verify -inform DER -noverify`

then i tried to verify it like below

```
openssl smime -verify -in apple-app-site-association -inform DER -content json -noverify -binary ServerCertificate.cer > /dev/null
```

i have no idea which certificate/key/file to put where ! i just tried as above, then i've got the below error

```
Verification failure
139806288791456:error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature:rsa_sign.c:293:
139806288791456:error:21071069:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_signatureVerify:signature failure:pk7_doit.c:1222:
139806288791456:error:21075069:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:signature failure:pk7_smime.c:410:
```

where i was doing wrong & help me resolving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, its resolved.

i've combined those chained certificates into one single certificate.crt using openssl commands, then i signed the apple association file with below command

```
sudo openssl smime -sign -signer my_combined_certificate.crt -inkey private.key -in json.txt -out apple-app-site-association
```

its worked , the deep linking is working now :)

**UPDATE 1**

if you have individual files instead of combined one, then with below command you can sign it.

```
cat file.json | openssl smime -sign -inkey privatefile.key -signer servercertificate.cer -certfile certficate.cer -noattr -nodetach -outform DER > apple-app-site-association
```

signer.cer

> servercertificate.cer --> having 3 chain certificates
>
> certificate.cer  --> have one ssl provider certificate
>
> privatefilekey.key -->is key file

Comment: ACertificate-1.cer
ACertificate-2.cer
ServerCertificate.cer
Private.key
How do i get all these certificate please explaine in brief

Comment: you have to buy ssl certificates from online provider, if they give you only single file then you can mail them to send seperate files as you need

Comment: ios dev job only is to create the apple json file (keeping which urls you want for deeplinking), rest of the work will be done by the sysadmin/other, who have to digitally sign that json file and to place it in ./well-known or root folder of the project